# THREE.PlaneGeometry doesn't get rendered

Tags: three.js

I've tried playing around with the tutorial from aerotwist. Everything went well, until I messed with THREE.PlaneGeometry, as the code below:

```
var $container = $('#container');
var WIDTH = $container.width(), HEIGHT = $container.height();
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 10000;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera.position.z = 300;
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
$container.append(renderer.domElement);

// create the mesh's material
var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xCC0000});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,1,1),meshMaterial);

// add the mesh to the scene
scene.add(mesh);
scene.add(camera);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

When I change the line from

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,1,1),meshMaterial);
```

to

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100,1,1),meshMaterial);
```

or

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100),meshMaterial);
```

Then nothing is rendered. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that its not double sided or that you can't see it on its current angle, check this [js fiddle of plane rotating](http://jsfiddle.net/NycWc/21/) and play around with that one for practice.

**EDIT:**

Looks like the plane faces down so the camera can't see it, I changed the `mesh.rotation.x` to prove it does render.

See - [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/NycWc/23/)

Comment: I've checked using FireBug, the plane and camera, and their rotations etc. didn't seem to have problem...

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of your example?

Answer (score 0):

Neil's answer is what I'd try first; it may also be that your scale (in at least one axis) is set to 0 or NaN.